# Simple Cash Register programm on C

Tags: c, types, floating-point, double

The program asks for the price input, then adds gst (13%) to it. Then, it should output the required amount of different coins to be paid (loonies=1 dollar, quarters=0.25, dimes=0.1, nickels=0.05, pennies=0.01).

Actually, I almost managed to do everything by myself, however the last part where it should output number of pennies is not working properly for me.

For example: 
When I input 8.32, this is what I get

---

Please enter the amount to be paid: $8.32

GST: 1.09

Balance owing: 9.41

Loonies required: 9, balance owing $0.41

Quarters required: 1, balance owing $0.16

Dimes required: 1, balance owing $0.06

Nickels required: 1, balance owing $0.01

Pennies required: 0, balance owing $0.01

---

Clearly the second last line says there is 0.01 outstanding balance, however the program tells that 0 pennies are required.

I think the problem is in types, but they are not so clear to me yet.

***Code***

```
                                                                            // Presenting needed variables for this task
double amount;                                                          // We ask a customer to input the amount
int loonies, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies;                                                         // Loonies and quarters represent single number of coins, therefore they are integer values
float owing, gst;

printf("Please enter the amount to be paid: $");                                // Asking to enter the input
scanf("%lf", &amount);

gst = amount * .13 + .005;
printf("GST: %.2f\n", gst);

owing = amount + gst;
printf("Balance owing: %.2f\n", owing);

loonies = owing;                                                                // By assigning loonies to amount, we calculate the integer amount of loonies we can fit into the amount number
owing = owing - loonies;                                                    // Calculating the owing amount left to pay


printf("Loonies required: %d, balance owing $%.2f\n", loonies, owing);          // Showing the amount of required loonies and the rest of owing balance

quarters = owing / 0.25;                                                        // Calculating amount of quarters to pay
owing = owing - quarters * 0.25;                                                    // Calculating the rest of the amount left to pay

printf("Quarters required: %d, balance owing $%.2f\n", quarters, owing);        // Showing the amount of required quarters and the rest of owing balance

dimes = owing / 0.1;
owing = owing - dimes * 0.1;

printf("Dimes required: %d, balance owing $%.2f\n", dimes, owing);

nickels = owing / 0.05;
owing = owing - nickels * 0.05;

printf("Nickels required: %d, balance owing $%.2f\n", nickels, owing);


pennies = owing / 0.01;
owing = owing - pennies * 0.01;

printf("Pennies required: %d, balance owing $%.2f\n", pennies, owing);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Float numbers have errors, they are not exact, you would be better using cent calculations...

Comment: What are Loonies, Quarter and so on? I read they are coins, but I never heard about it

Comment: @Cid Loonies = 1 dollar Quarter = 0.25 Dimes = 0.1 Nickels = 0.05 Pennies= 0.01. Theese are Canadian coins.

Comment: @Grady Player What do you exactly mean by cent calculations?

Comment: @Nightingale Would you please edit your question and add those informations?

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to take the total in dollars & vents, multiply by 100 to get cents, convert it to an int, and do integer arithmetic after that. Integer division will get you the number of coins, then a modulus operation will get you to the next step. Oh, and stay away from floats and doubles before you get to integers, do the original operations in decimal. Pennies? Pennies don't exist in Canada anymore. Instead of adding 0.005 for rounding, pick a rounding strategy and use Matjh.Round

Comment: Consider $4.37. Multiply by 100 & convert to an int and you get 437. Divide by 100 (cents in a loonie) and get 4. Do `437 % 100` and you get 37 remaining. Divide by 25 and get 1, after a modulus 25, you get 12. 12 div 10 is 1, 12%10 is 2. Divide 2 by 5 and you get 0. 2%5 is 2, and that's how may pennies you get. You could do this with twoonies (2 C$ coins), and 5, 10, 20, 50 & 100 bills as well. If you want to be fancy, create a `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>` that contains the name of the bill or coin and its value in cents, and do all this in a loop

Comment: Sorry, I somehow mixed up C and C#. My collection is NET specific. You'd obviously be using C language collection if you wanted to do this in a loop.